# Run Cypress.io on Azure Pipelines Hosted Linux Agent

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, cypress, github-actions, azure-pipelines-release-pipeline

I'm trying to run Cypress tests on the Hosted Linux Pool for Azure Pipelines. Unfortunately, the Hosted Agent doesn't have all the dependencies for Cypress installed.

Running the documented `apt-get` doesn't work:

```
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7423331Z ##[section]Starting: Install cypress dependencies
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7474742Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7488281Z Task         : Bash
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7501148Z Description  : This is an early preview. Run a Bash script on macOS, Linux, or Windows
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7513088Z Version      : 3.127.0
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7524823Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7537179Z Help         : [More Information](https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=613738)
2018-05-18T21:03:14.7549730Z ==============================================================================
2018-05-18T21:03:15.0174503Z Generating script.
2018-05-18T21:03:15.0535056Z Script contents:
2018-05-18T21:03:15.0547355Z apt-get install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2
2018-05-18T21:03:15.0656822Z [command]/bin/bash --noprofile --norc /opt/vsts/work/_temp/cac4d3f9-42e7-49f3-94f6-7d0444827d83.sh
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6040707Z Reading package lists...
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6085335Z Building dependency tree...
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6153815Z Reading state information...
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6186788Z Package libgconf-2-4 is not available, but is referred to by another package.
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6198707Z This may mean that the package is missing, has been obsoleted, or
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6211380Z is only available from another source
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6216969Z 
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6229592Z E: Unable to locate package xvfb
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6242128Z E: Unable to locate package libnotify-dev
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6254440Z E: Package 'libgconf-2-4' has no installation candidate
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6268141Z E: Unable to locate package libxss1
2018-05-18T21:03:15.6370826Z ##[error]Bash exited with code '100'.
2018-05-18T21:03:15.7283047Z ##[section]Finishing: Install cypress dependencies
```

Running `apt-get update` takes forever (25 minutes and still not done).

Any clues on how to get Cypress working quickly on the Hosted Agent is welcome.

**Note:** I tried running on Windows, that works, fortunately, so I'm not completely blocked. But to use the Windows Agent I now have 2 agent phases which adds overhead due to artefact downloads and npm install overhead.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Solved the issue using a pre-pended Shell (Bash) task in VSTS agent phase prior to running Cypress:

```
apt-get -qq -y update
apt-get -qq -y install xvfb libgtk2.0-0 libnotify-dev libgconf-2-4 libnss3 libxss1 libasound2
```

Comment: I get this error: Could not open lock file /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (13: Permission denied)