# Install program on Azure Pipelines

Tags: azure, azure-pipelines

so I've got some CI set up with Azure Pipelines, everything is nice, except I'd like to add some checks for memory errors, as I have on Travis currently. In Travis, I can write:

```
addons:
  apt:
    packages:
- valgrind
```

and it will install valgrind for me. I've been unable to find the equivalent feature on Azure Pipelines, but there has to be a way to do this.

I've searched through their docs in vain already, any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

In a script task, you can just run the required commands yourself. Looks like you're using a Hosted Ubuntu agent.

```
- script: |
  sudo apt-get install -qq -y valgrind
  valgrind
```

(written without syntax validation, you may need to tweak this a little).

Similar to [how I installed all required dependencies for Cypress on the Hosted Agent](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50419871/run-cypress-io-on-vsts-hosted-linux).

Comment: it complains that `apt does not have a stable CLI interface. Use with caution in scripts.`, but this worked, so thanks.

Comment: for future reference to anyone reading this, exact command was: `sudo apt install valgrind`

Comment: use `apt-get` in scripts, and `apt` for humans